# SQL Datatype for math operation that having string

Tags: sql, oracle

i want to make **price column** that have value like this **Rp27.375** since i will doing some math operation with this column i cant use varchar dataype and neither with number datatype because the column will have some string. Can someone provide me a way to solve my problem ? thanks

Comment: Keep different columns for unit(varchar2) and actual value(number)

Comment: Totally agree with @Tejash

Comment: mysql or oracle?

Comment: @tejash i dont get it, so i will combine the columns later ?

Comment: @Jens its oracle, i put it both together because i thought its no different when discuss about datatype

Comment: A price isn't a string. It's a number. The fact that you're combining some sort of a string with a price is an indicator of a data model that needs to be fixed. Why do you believe you need to combine them in the first place?

Comment: it seems you're storing the currency with the price. As others have said, keep them in different columns. When you want to print them, concatenate them

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem of database design. You need to store it in different columns as others have mentioned in the comments. But if you still want to save it in a single column you need to use SUBSTR function as SUBSTR(price,3,15) which will trim the currency code for you and then need to convert the result into number using to_nummber function.